# Another R error: "comparison of these types is not implemented"

Tags: r, function, dataframe

This works as a standalone statement, but errors when implemented in a function:
Given a data frame dummyDF with columns Status and LastStatusChangeDate, this works:

```
> nrow(dummyDF[which(dummyDF$Status == "Confirmed" & dummyDF$LastStatusChangeDate < as.Date("2018-11-30")),])
[1] 9
```

But when I implement it in a function:

```
QueueLength <- function(df, Status, LastDate){
  nrow(df[which(df$Status == Status & df$LastStatusChangeDate < as.Date(LastDate)),])
}
```

and call it thus:

```
QueueLength(dummyDF, "Confirmed", "2018-11-30")
```

I get this error:
    Error in df$Status == Status : 
  comparison of these types is not implemented

So what is the type difference? I ran this line:

```
> typeof(dummyDF$Status)
[1] "list"
```

OK, so I'm trying to compare a single string to a list of strings. I get it, sort of, why that is a problem, but it doesn't account for the body of the function working perfectly fine when I execute it interactively as above.

Anyone have a thought on how to make this work in a function?
Thanks.

Comment: can you provide dummyDF so we can reproduce the error?

Comment: Furher noodling around revealed that the "Status" column was produced by using lapply which created the values as a nested list. I wrapped the lapply() in unlist() and that cured THAT problem. One of these days I'll get my head around the apply() family. The error message has disappeared, but the function looks like it's only using the "LastStatusChangeDate" value in filtering. I'll work on it some more tomorrow and post again. Thanks.

Comment: ``QueueLength <- function(df, Status, LastDate){
  nrow(df[which(df$`Status` == Status & df$LastStatusChangeDate < as.Date(LastDate)),])
}`` doesn't work too?

Comment: I never worked out what the problem was, but when I created dummDF as a tibble rather than as a dataframe, my problems disappeared. Generally I like to stick with base R, but there are good reasons these other packages exist. Hats off to Tidyverse.